# Set default fields in reducer to yet unknown object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer with `INITIAL_STATE = {}` and then as certain actions are dispatched I populate it with some data e.g `[key]: {name: 'john'}, ...`.

Is it possible to set some default fields to those kind of objects?
For example, if it is a reducer that will be populated with people objects
the default field can be `{nationality: 'kazakh'}`.

Comment: can you elaborate your question please? What do you mean by default fields? show an example if possible

Comment: @Umesh updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! This would be done as part of your reducer. Let's say you had an action to add a User with the shape

```
{
    id,
    name,
    email,
    emailVerified,
}
```

and you wanted the `emailVerfied` field to default to `false` in the case that it wasn't part of the action payload.

You could write something like the following:

```
const userDefaults = {
    emailVerified: false
};

function userReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'user.add':
            return Object.assign(state, {
                [action.payload.id]: Object.assign({}, userDefaults, action.payload)
            });
    }
}
```

The nested `Object.assign` will create a new object that merges the defaults and the action payload, preferring values in the action payload over any defaults.

Comment: thanks @casieber, your andwer is good, but I think I stated my problem wrong